# How to implement JWT with Keycloak in Spring boot microservice acrhitecture?

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, microservices, keycloak, api-gateway

I have read some articles for Keycloak spring implementation (eg: [easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/05/25/easily-secure-your-spring-boot-applications-with-keycloak/)) but no one mention how to use with JWT.

I have created zuul api gateway and add Keycloak adapter as described in the previously linked article. That's ok, but I want to use JWT with keycloak.

Mentioned elsewhere set the client access type to bearer-only and the session strategy to NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy. That's enough or need something else for JWT?

So my questions:

- How do I configure client on Keycloak admin for JWT?
- How do I configure Keycloak in backend config file for JWT?
- How do I configure Keycloak adapter for JWT?
- How do I pass user info to microservice? Create filter in gateway? But how I get user info from request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keycloak access token is a `JWT`. It is a `JSON` and each field in that `JSON` is called a `claim`. By default, logged in `username` is returned in a `claim` named `“preferred_username”` in `access token`. Spring Security OAuth2 Resource Server expects username in a `claim` named `“user_name”`. So, you need to create mapper to map logged in `username` to a new `claim` named `user_name`.

In order to provide access to client (micro-service), respective `role` needs to be assigned/mapped to `user`.

In your spring boot application, then you need to configure connection to keycloak server, providing, `auth` url, `token` url, `scope`, `grant-type`, `client-id` and `client-secret`.

Afterthat, your app be able to parse JWT token, you need to create some `JwtAccessTokenCustomizer`. This class should extend `DefaultAccessTokenConverter` and implement `JwtAccessTokenConverterConfigurer` classes. The main logic lays in `public OAuth2Authentication extractAuthentication(Map<String, ?> tokenMap)` method.

Then you need to configure `OAuth2 Resource Server` to provide access for other micro services. For that you define here - `Oauth2RestTemplate` Bean.

And in the end, secure your REST API, via the standard configuration `Component`.

So, you can see that, it is a large work, and couldn't be described with code, show some of your work, divide it to the chunk, and ask interesting your questions.